# I will say he is 60 years old

Tags: modal-verbs

A: What's his age?

B1: I say he is 60 years old.

B2: I **would** say he is 60 years old.

B3: I **will** say he is 60 years old.

Do they all sound correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer? Yes they are all correct. I see only slight differences, which are not always intended.

B1 is a simple statement.

B2 is a conditional statement, suggesting that you vaguely admit to a little doubt about it.

B3 is a future statement, suggesting that you are still vaguely considering the evidence for it.

Comment: B3 is not necessarily a future statement; it can express, for example, that the speaker is willing to say he is 60 without regards to the veracity of that statement, or the consequences of making it,

Comment: To me, B3 sounds like an answer to the first two statements, as if three people were trying to guess someone's age. The third person wants to throw in his opinion.

Comment: I agree with both comments.

Answer (score 1):

In most circumstances, B2 "I would say he is 60 years old" is the most natural phrasing.

"I will say he is 60 years old" could be a statement about the future (in answer to "How old will you say he is, if anyone asks?") or it could just be a guess about his age (although in British English, "I'm going to say he's 60 years old" would work better for this usage).

"I say he is 60 years old" is a more confident-sounding suggestion.

As a guess about his age, "I say" and "I will say" both sound more colloquial than "I would say".

Comment: So when we want to **guess** something, we can use "I **will** say...". Can we use "I **will** think..." to guess something too? For example: *By the time Felix turned up it was early afternoon, which, I **will** think, would be late enough.*

Comment: I don't think so - I think it has to be "I would think" (or "I think" or, in southern BrE, "I should think").

Comment: OK. Is it just that example or does it sound incorrect in this example too: "I **will** think he is 60 years old." (the speaker is making a guess)

Comment: It sounds incorrect in that example, too.

Answer (score 1):

None of these say he is 60 years old. Some sound like an opinion, others like a preparation for a lie.

How old is Mick Jagger? I say he is sixty years old - just your opinion, and wrong. I would say he is 60 years old - another guess.

Your dad is 58, so he can’t get the pensioner price for a ticket. I will say he is 60 - you are prepared to lie to save a bit of money.

How old is your dad? He is sixty. That’s the truth unless you are completely wrong or a practical joker.